# C++ includes, class namespacing, and class instantiation

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I've been writing some code to try and model some kind of taxi service, but I've run into a bit of an issue.

I have a class *RunServer*, which looks at the state of commands given by the user (*src::control::Global::stat_commandPath*) and asks for additional input based on those commands before doing something with that input.

The problem is that I'm getting an "error: expected type-specifier" (GCC-7.3.0, C++11) and it looks like it might have something to do with how I've namespaced the classes. If *namespace* declarations are removed from **src/Vehicle/Car.h**, then this problem stops happening.

This is should be all the relevant code for this issue. Sorry there's so much of it, I've truncated everything that doesn't look like it has an impact. The problem is with **src/control/RunServer.h** lines 66, 70, and 74. **src/vehicle/Pickup.h** and **src/vehicle/Van.h** have the same structure as **src/vehicle/Car.h**.

**src/control/Global.h**

```cxx
#ifndef INCLUDED_src_control_Global_h
#define INCLUDED_src_control_Global_h

#include <string>

#include "../vehicle/Vehicle.h"


namespace src {
namespace control {


    class Global final
    {
        virtual void instantiable() = 0;

        private:

            static size_t
                stat_vehicleArrayLength;

            static src::Vehicle
            ** stat_vehicleArray;

        public:

            static std::string
                stat_commandPath,
                stat_stdcoutEnd;

        public:

            static bool
                // Deletes the pointer argument if adding fails.
                add_vehicle(
                    src::Vehicle *
                ),
                exists_vehicle(
                    std::string
                ),
                remove_vehicle(
                    std::string
                );

            static size_t
                get_vehicleAmount(),
                position_vehicle(
                    std::string
                );

            static src::Vehicle
            ** get_vehicles();
    };


}}


#endif
```

**src/control/RunServer.cpp**

```cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit()
#include <string>
#include <regex>

#include "../../lib/StringTools.h"
#include "../vehicle/Car.h"
#include "../vehicle/Pickup.h"
#include "../vehicle/Van.h"
#include "../vehicle/VehicleType.h"
#include "../person/Driver.h"
#include "../person/Passenger.h"
#include "Global.h"
#include "RunServer.h"


inline bool
src::control::RunServer::navigation(
    std::string input)
{
    if (input == "return")
    {
        src::control::Global::stat_commandPath.pop_back();
        return true;
    }
    if (input == "exit")
    {
        exit(0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void
src::control::RunServer::run()
{
    std::string input;

    // "0"   ~ Create...
    // "00"  ~ Create > Vehicle...
    // "000" ~ Create > Vehicle > Car
    // "001" ~ Create > Vehicle > Pickup
    // "002" ~ Create > Vehicle > Van
    // "01"  ~ Create > Person...
    // "010" ~ Create > Person > Driver
    // "011" ~ Create > Person > Passenger
    // "1"   ~ Destroy...
    // "10"  ~ Destroy > Vehicle
    // "11"  ~ Destroy > Passenger
    // "2"   ~ Print

    if (src::control::Global::stat_commandPath == "000" || src::control::Global::stat_commandPath == "001" || src::control::Global::stat_commandPath == "002")
    {
        // Create > Vehicle > (Car|Pickup|Van).
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "<vehicle identification (char array)>" << src::control::Global::stat_stdcoutEnd;
        getline(std::cin, input);

        if (src::control::RunServer::navigation(input))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (std::regex_match(input, std::regex("\\w+")))
        {
            if (src::control::Global::stat_commandPath.back() == '0' && !src::control::Global::add_vehicle(new src::vehicle::Car(input)))
            {
                std::cout << "\nA vehicle with this identifier already exists!\n";
            }
            else if (src::control::Global::stat_commandPath.back() == '1' && !src::control::Global::add_vehicle(new src::vehicle::Pickup(input)))
            {
                std::cout << "\nA vehicle with this identifier already exists!\n";
            }
            else if (src::control::Global::stat_commandPath.back() == '2' && !src::control::Global::add_vehicle(new src::vehicle::Van(input)))
            {
                std::cout << "\nA vehicle with this identifier already exists!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nAn error occured!\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**src/vehicle/Car.h**

```cxx
#ifndef INCLUDED_src_vehicle_Car_h
#define INCLUDED_src_vehicle_Car_h

#include <string>

#include "Vehicle.h"


namespace src {
namespace vehicle {


    class Car final : public src::Vehicle
    {
        void instantiable() override {};

        public:

            Car();
            Car(
                std::string
            );

            int
                canAddPassenger(
                    src::person::Passenger *
                ) override;
    };


}}


#endif
```

Comment: Nested namespaces in the application domain are typically a bad idea, particularly for beginners. What does `namespace src ` even mean?

Comment: `namespace src` refers to that the file is located in the **src/...** directory. I'm used to Haxe so I'm trying to emulate it's [module and path syntax](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html)

Comment: That does not seem like a good thing to do for C++ code - there is no relationship between type/class/namespace names and directories or file names in C++.

Comment: Alright, I'll try underscore-seperated namspaces then.

Comment: No that's not a good idea either - just get rid of the namespaces. And have you actually read a C++ textbook?

Comment: I just tried the underscores for **src/vehicle/Car.h** and that's fixed it. Nested namespacing was the problem then. Why is it better to not use namespaces?

Comment: Because they are not necessary. I can't imagine how adding underscores could have "fixed" anything.

Comment: Yeah it turns out it didn't. When I just changed the namespacing of `src::vehicle::Car` to `src_vehicle::Car` it worked but then when I changed it for `src::vehicle::Pickup` and `src::vehicle::Van` I was getting the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue appears to be related to case. It seems like namespace lookup is not case sensitive while namespace declaration is. Changing the namespace of `src::vehicle::Car` to `src::avehicle::Car` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong:

```
        static bool
            // Deletes the pointer argument if adding fails.
            add_vehicle(
                src::Vehicle *
            ),
            exists_vehicle(
                std::string
            ),
            remove_vehicle(
                std::string
            );
```

What are you trying to accomplish here? Isn't this supposed to be 3 independent prototypes?

```
        static bool
            // Deletes the pointer argument if adding fails.
            add_vehicle(
                src::Vehicle *
            );
        static bool exists_vehicle(
                std::string
            );
        static bool remove_vehicle(
                std::string
            );
```

Comment: I thought you could declare multiple functions/variables of the same type by separating them with a comma?

Comment: I saw variables in the past, but even this is a bad practice. Then you may want to give us more details, like the error and where it comes from (i.e. line).

Comment: Dangit I thought I was forgetting something! I'll put that in right now.

Comment: @0x.dummyVar No you can't declare multiple functions separated by a comma.

Comment: Yeah it's probably bad form, I'll change it.

Comment: "src/control/RunServer.h lines 66, 70, and 74" is still not enough to tell us exactly what is going on. Can you show the actual error?

Comment: Just an FYI, there is no RunServer.h in what you gave us.